# How to configure my database relations so I can insert my entities?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have a stack

```
type Stack struct {
    Name             string           `json:"name" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Parameters       []StackParameter `json:"parameters" gorm:"foreignKey:StackName; references: Name; constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE"`
    ...
}
```

The `Stack` has some parameters. Multiple stacks can have the same parameter therefore I use the parameter `Name` and the `StackName` as a primary composite key

```
type StackParameter struct {
    Name         string  `json:"name" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    StackName    string  `json:"-" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    DefaultValue *string `json:"defaultValue"`
    ...
}
```

I want to be able to deploy a chain of stacks. So I have a chain

```
type Chain struct {
    ID          uint      `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Name        string `json:"name" gorm:"index:idx_name_and_group,unique"`
    Description string `json:"description"`
    GroupName   string `json:"groupName" gorm:"index:idx_name_and_group,unique; references:Name"`
    Group       *Group `json:"group,omitempty"`
    Links       []*Link `json:"links"`
}
```

The `Chain` have some links

```
type Link struct {
    ID        uint      `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    ChainID uint  `json:"chainId"`
    Chain   Chain `json:"chain"`

    StackName string `json:"stackName" gorm:"references:Name"`
    Stack     Stack  `json:"stack"`
    Parameters []*LinkParameter `json:"parameters" gorm:"foreignKey:LinkID"`
}
```

A `Link` is an instance of a `Stack`, think of it as class/object, so it has parameters with `Name`'s defined by the `Stack`'s parameters

```
type LinkParameter struct {
    LinkID         uint           `json:"linkId" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Name           string         `json:"name" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    StackParameter StackParameter `json:"-" gorm:"foreignKey:Name,StackName; references:Name,StackName; constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE"`
    StackName      string         `json:"-"`
    Value          string         `json:"value"`
}
```

So a `LinkParameter` belongs to a `Link` and has a unique name defined by a `StackParameter` and defines the `Value` for those two.

I'll leave out my handler, service and repository code for the sake of brevity but the main goal is to save a `Link` with `LinkParameter`'s and I'm trying to do that using

```
err := r.db.Session(&gorm.Session{FullSaveAssociations: true}).Save(link).Error
```

But I'm getting the following error

```
[im-manager] 2023/08/13 09:29:21 /src/pkg/instance/repository.go:50 ERROR: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification (SQLSTATE 42P10)
[im-manager] [0.291ms] [rows:0] INSERT INTO "link_parameters" ("link_id","stack_parameter_name","stack_name","value") VALUES (5,'STARTUP_PROBE_FAILURE_THRESHOLD','whoami-go','STARTUP_PROBE_FAILURE_THRESHOLD'),(5,'STARTUP_PROBE_PERIOD_SECONDS','whoami-go','STARTUP_PROBE_PERIOD_SECONDS') ON CONFLICT ("link_id","stack_parameter_name") DO UPDATE SET "stack_name"="excluded"."stack_name","value"="excluded"."value"
[im-manager] 
[im-manager] 2023/08/13 09:29:21 /src/pkg/instance/repository.go:50 ERROR: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification (SQLSTATE 42P10)
[im-manager] [1.279ms] [rows:1] INSERT INTO "links" ("created_at","updated_at","chain_id","stack_name","preset","preset_id","public","deploy_log") VALUES ('2023-08-13 09:29:21.319','2023-08-13 09:29:21.319',1,'whoami-go',false,0,false,'') RETURNING "id"
```

CONTEXT UPDATE:

The thing I'm actually trying to do is to go from deploying one `Instance` to deploy a `Chain` of instances which I now call `Link`'s. And that has been working for a long time now. So I'm basically just trying to split the [`Instance`](https://github.com/dhis2-sre/im-manager/blob/21641410f5df2df347d88617b2372ea8caeac701/pkg/model/instance.go#L48) struct in to a [`Chain`](https://github.com/dhis2-sre/im-manager/blob/21641410f5df2df347d88617b2372ea8caeac701/pkg/model/instance.go#L8) struct with [`Link`](https://github.com/dhis2-sre/im-manager/blob/21641410f5df2df347d88617b2372ea8caeac701/pkg/model/instance.go#L26)'s.

Based on @TiGo's suggestions I'm now getting

```
[im-manager] 2023/08/14 03:27:24 /src/pkg/instance/repository.go:54 ERROR: ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE requires inference specification or constraint name (SQLSTATE 42601)
[im-manager] [0.237ms] [rows:0] INSERT INTO "link_parameters" ("link_id","stack_parameter_name","stack_name","value") VALUES (18,'REPLICA_COUNT','whoami-go','1'),(18,'IMAGE_PULL_POLICY','whoami-go','Always') ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET "link_id"="excluded"."link_id","stack_parameter_name"="excluded"."stack_parameter_name","stack_name"="excluded"."stack_name","value"="excluded"."value"
[im-manager] 
[im-manager] 2023/08/14 03:27:24 /src/pkg/instance/repository.go:54 ERROR: ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE requires inference specification or constraint name (SQLSTATE 42601)
[im-manager] [2.106ms] [rows:1] INSERT INTO "links" ("created_at","updated_at","chain_id","stack_name","preset","preset_id","public","deploy_log") VALUES ('2023-08-14 03:27:24.802','2023-08-14 03:27:24.802',1,'whoami-go',false,0,false,'') RETURNING "id"
```

ANOTHER UPDATE:

This seems to work if I change the `Name` property of the `LinkParameter` struct to `ParameterName` so it'll look like this

```
type LinkParameter struct {
    LinkID         uint           `json:"-" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    ParameterName  string         `json:"name" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    StackParameter StackParameter `json:"-" gorm:"foreignKey:ParameterName,StackName; references:Name,StackName; constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE"`
    StackName      string         `json:"-"`
    Value          string         `json:"value"`
}
```

Can anyone tell my why it has to be that way?

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because your `LinkParameter` table does not have a unique constraint on `(link_id, stack_parameter_name)` that matches the ON CONFLICT clause.

When doing an INSERT with ON CONFLICT, PostgreSQL requires a unique index/constraint to exist on the columns specified in ON CONFLICT. This allows it to detect conflicts correctly.

To fix it, you need to add a unique constraint on `(link_id, stack_parameter_name)` in the `LinkParameter` table:

```golang
type LinkParameter struct {
  //...

  LinkID string `gorm:"uniqueIndex:link_param_idx"` 
  Name string `gorm:"uniqueIndex:link_param_idx"`

  // ...
}
```

This will create a unique constraint "link_param_idx" on (link_id, name).

Then your ON CONFLICT will work as expected.
So in summary:

- Add unique index on the columns specified in ON CONFLICT
- This allows PostgreSQL to detect conflicts on insert
- Then the ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE clause will trigger correctly

Comment: Thanks for a well written answer. I'm now getting a new error but I'm honestly not sure if that's step back or forward. I've update the question with the error and bit more context. As I explain, I'm really confused about why this is happening because I already had an Instance with parameters and I'm just trying to add a parent Chain struct around it.

Comment: I got it working, please see my update above